# Change attribute back to before calculated attribute in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to change the attribute of an element back to it's old color after a onclick event in d3. problem is that the old color got calculated by a scale within a function.

I want to hightlight a selected country in a map in d3 and change back the color when I highlight another country.

```
            d3.selectAll('.buurt').on('click', function(data){
            var postcode = data.properties.postcode;
            piechart(property_types, svg_piechart1, postcode);



            kaart(data_buurten, data_geo, svg_kaart, key)
            // verander kleur van selection
            var selected_color = '#FF0000' // red
            selected = d3.select(this).select('path').attr('fill', function(d) { return selected_color });
```

function kaart(data, data_geo, svg_kaart, key) {

```
// verwijder
svg_kaart.selectAll('g').remove();

// maak groep ('g') en bind data
var group = svg_kaart.selectAll('g')
    .data(data_geo.features)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'buurt');

array_key_data = Object.values(data).map(function(i){return i[key]})
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, array_key_data)
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, array_key_data)
var color_scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([min, max]).range(['#e5f5f9','#99d8c9', '#2ca25f'])
var areas = group.append("path")
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('class', 'area')
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
        postcode_geo_data = d.properties.postcode
        data_per_buurt = data[postcode_geo_data]
        // als er een plek is zonder postcode
        if (data_per_buurt === undefined) {
            var red = '#FF0000'
            return red
        } else {
            // als er een plek is met postcode
            value = data_per_buurt[key]
            return color_scale(value)

        }
    })
    .attr('id', function(d){ return d.properties.postcode})
```

}

Comment: If you want help, you have to share some code. But why don't you simply use the same function you used to fill the path the first time?

Comment: Good question. I've updated my answer with the code. But basicly if I redraw the map (this) wont excist anymore. Function 'kaart' is the one which draws the map.

Comment: I'll add the function kaart 2. Sec

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is just using the **same color scale** for all elements inside the click function (*before* painting the clicked element, of course). Here is a simple demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [5, 30, 50, 80, 100];
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range(["greenyellow", "darkgreen"])
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 30 + 60 * i
  })
  .attr("stroke", "gray")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return scale(d)
  })
  .attr("cursor", "pointer");

circles.on("click", function() {
  circles.attr("fill", function(d) {
    return scale(d)
  });
  d3.select(this).attr("fill", "firebrick");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Despite being easy, that is not a clever solution, because it repaints *all* the elements. For modern, fast browsers, it works just nice if you have a small amount of elements.

However, if you have a huge amount of elements, a better alternative to save resources is repainting only the clicked element and the previously clicked element. For instance:

```
var clickedElement, elementColour;

selection.on("click", function(d, i, n) {
    if (clickedElement) {
        clickedElement.attr("fill", elementColour);
    };
    clickedElement = d3.select(this);
    elementColour = d3.select(this).attr("fill");
    d3.select(this).attr("fill", "firebrick");
});
```

In this snippet, `clickedElement` holds the reference to the previously clicked element, and `elementColour` holds its color. Then, after repainting the previously clicked element, `clickedElement` is associated to the currently clicked element, as well as `elementColour`.

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [5, 30, 50, 80, 100];
var clickedElement, elementColour;
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range(["greenyellow", "darkgreen"])
var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 30 + 60 * i
  })
  .attr("stroke", "gray")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return scale(d)
  })
  .attr("cursor", "pointer");

circles.on("click", function(d,i,n) {
  if(clickedElement){clickedElement.attr("fill", elementColour);};
      clickedElement= d3.select(this);
      elementColour = d3.select(this).attr("fill");
      d3.select(this).attr("fill", "firebrick");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've made use of giving classes. Anyways thanks for the help because I think you mentioned that, right.